# TcxDBDateEdit DisplayFormat yyyy-mm-dd hh:nn

Tags: delphi, date, format

How to set the date and time format for cxDBDateEdit to properly always display format:
yyy-mm-dd hh:nn.

If the component loses focus it is ok, but for editing is displayed, eg.:
2014-02-05 16:30:00 (including seconds)

Answer (score 0):

Under the Properties of the control there is a `DisplayFormat` property and also a `EditFormat` property. Does setting those both to `yyyy-mm-dd hh:nn` solve your problem?

Comment: When I set DisplayFormat it is OK, but when I set DisplayFormat and EditFormat and the component has focus I see it 2014-02-05 (without hours and minutes)

Comment: Hmm, that's odd. I just tested with a `TcxDateEdit` it and I see it with the hours and minutes (as expected). What version of Dev Express are you using? I don't know why the DB control would be different.

Comment: I use DBdateEdit - the field is plugged into SQL CE as a datetime. This may SQL ce gives higher priority to the mask?